# application compatible to mobile as well as Tablet

Tags: android, android-version, android-compatibility

I want to make an application compatible to mobile as well as tablet.Please suggest me how can i do that?
Do i need to make two separate application or one application will solve my purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default all apps are compatible with all shapes and sizes (the only restriction being API level). Apps will resize automatically dependent on screen size - whether it does it correctly is another matter.

You can (and should) redesign the app so that it appears correctly on all devices. This means taking advantage of the specific folder structure Android uses: there is plenty of information on the subject on the Android Dev Guide at

- http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

There is no need, however, to make a separate app.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the android developers section for what you want [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit generic. But here are some points:

1. Android provides enough mechanisms to deal with devices with different OS, sizes and capabilities.
2. From an OS perspective, ensure that the APIs are available across older versions and if not, Android does provide compatibility/support JARs to address that.
3. From a size perspective, you will need to ensure that the resources (images especially) are created for small, medium, large and x-large dpis. You will also need to ensure that layouts are created for appropriate sizes so that your application is presented in an optimum way as far as usability is concerned.

These are just some points but hopefully they give you a preview of various areas to consider.